# Limit topology of a sequence of topological vector spaces

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

Under which circumstances is the limit topology of an increasing sequence $E_0\subseteq E_1\subseteq E_2\subseteq\cdots$ of topological vector spaces, where the inclusion maps are linear and continuous, again a linear topology w.r.t. the linear space $\cup_i E_i$?

Comment: what is t.v.s. ?

Comment: Topological vector space, will write it out, sorry.